# Problem with rqt, siplib.c - KDE Neon

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm use KDE Neon as main system and have the problem with rqt.
Launching any rqt program I have thу same answer.

$ rqt

python: siplib.c:12299: sipEnumType_alloc: Assertion `sipTypeIsEnum(currentType)' failed.

Aborted

Maybe anyone know how to fix it, or can give me advice about debug this problem ?

Thanks.

p.s. Yes, I now that KDE Neon is not recommended system for ROS. But changing the system because one program did'n work - is not a linux-way.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256724/problem-with-rqt,-siplib.c---kde-neon/) by [Aiven](https://answers.ros.org/users/29656/aiven/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-03-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2017-03-27**:
Have you solved this? I'm switching to neon from kubuntu just now because of desktop issues.

**Comment by [Pascal Becker](https://answers.ros.org/users/29842/pascal-becker/) on 2017-03-27**:
Some colleagues and me struggle with the same issue... Hope it is fixed soon!

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2017-03-27**:
I think there are more issues coming for us. Because no one tested ROS with newest Qt. If your usually used applications are kde based too, I suggest kubuntu. Because they aren't well configurable on unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved with last distr update (26.03.2017) - NO

edit 28.05.2017
I solve this problem with compile rtq by hand.

```
cd catkin_ws/src/
git clone https://github.com/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core.git
git clone https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt.git
git clone https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins.git
git clone https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_robot_plugins.git
cd ..
catkin_make install
```

I have some problems with compiling of rqt_gui. But all works.

---

Originally posted by [Aiven](https://answers.ros.org/users/29656/aiven/) with karma: 21 on 2017-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pascal Becker](https://answers.ros.org/users/29842/pascal-becker/) on 2017-04-04**:
Just updated today, but the issue is still the same :-/

**Comment by [Aiven](https://answers.ros.org/users/29656/aiven/) on 2017-05-20**:
Confim. It's broke again =(

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-28**:
Have you reported any of this on the appropriate issue trackers?